# Getting lines across Legend symbol in ArcMap export to PDF?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, pdf

I am encountering an issue with an item in the legend when I use a page size of 36x48 for exported PDFs. The item, a library symbol, appears to have lines going through it. It looks fine with smaller page sizes. I have tried changing colors and enlarging the symbol, as well as opening up a new mxd and adding just the library data, but the problem persists.

Any solutions?[image: Screenshot of library symbol]

Comment: I think this needs a picture.

Comment: I see it only in exported pdf. I can send picture tomorrow

Comment: In addition to a picture, some details about your export settings, and maybe the symbol image itself (if it is a separate image) may be useful

Comment: Export settings: Resolution 300, CMYK. I posted a screenshot of the symbol.